# loading a JSON in AS3

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to load a JSON to my flash program. The JSON is in the same directory as the fla and swf file.  I am able to load the JSON to a string variable and when I do trace I see the JSON. The JSON format is valid, checked at: http://www.jsonlint.org/.
The problem is when I try to decode the JSON to an Object. 
I get the following error: "RangeError: Error #1506: The specified range is invalid." 
I am using the JSON lib from ac3corelib to decode the string.
Here is all the code:

```
import com.rational.serialization.json.JSON;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;

var _jsonLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
_jsonLoader.load(new URLRequest("JSON.json"));
_jsonLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processJson);
_jsonLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, _notify);

function _notify(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("error");
    e.target.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, _notify);
}
function processJson(e:Event):void
{
    var stringJson:String;
    var temp:Object;
    stringJson = String (e.target.data);
    trace(stringJson);
    temp = JSON.decode(stringJson);
trace(temp)
}
```

Please advise on to why I get this error

Thank you all,
Moshe S,

Comment: You might want to add the JSON code as well - it's a decoding error.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your JSON code, it is difficult to tell.  But, what version of Flash are you using?  Starting with Flash 11 and Air 3.0 (and Flex 4.6), you get native JSON support.

See if the native parser gives you any different information:

```
temp = JSON.parse(stringJson);
```

Comment: I need this to work with an AS3 project using Flash Player 9.

Comment: You might just create a small, sample project in FP11 and try it out?  Just to get some extra information about what is going on?  (or show us the JSON so we can help you better)

Comment: This is the JSON<br />{"pages": [{"pageId": "index","uiFlowType": "main","pageName": "Wellcome"},{"pageId": "contact","uiFlowType": "formRedirect","offerName": "ContactUs"}],"globalParams": {"users": [{"name": "admin","attributes": ["modify","DBAccess","userMAnger"],"pages": [{"name": "index","flows": ["masterpage","index"]}],"live": false}],"params": [{"key": "debug","value": "true"}],"strings": [{"key": "legalText","value": "apilegalsimpletext","enabled": true},{"key": "agrreementText","value": "<ahref='http: //www.google.com'><u>ClickHere</u></a>tocheckoursite", "enabled": true}]}}

Comment: Also I'm using flash player 9 (this is the request from my customer)

Comment: I copied your code (pretty much) directly with your data and it decoded just fine.  What does your stack trace say when you get the exception?  `trace(e.error.getStackTrace())`

Comment: Hi, 
When I add the trace to the catch I get the following: 
   RangeError: Error #1506: The specified range is invalid.
Another thing is that when I publish the code with flash player 10.3 it works fine, but when I publish the code for player version 9 I get the errors.

Comment: What is the output of `trace(stringJson)` ? The JSON you posted above contains a <br /> tag before the JSON object which won't parse.

Comment: The br tag was inserted here in the hope of breaking a line before showing the JSON. The tag is not part of the code